# Showing that the $\lim s_n\neq\dfrac{2}{3}$ when $s_n=\dfrac{2}{3n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

I'm trying to verify if I what I did to show that limit does not exist is valid using the negation of the definition: 
$\exists \epsilon>0, \forall N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N \implies |s_n-s|\ge \epsilon$.

Proof

Let $\epsilon=\dfrac{1}{2}$. Then for sufficiently large $n$, we get $|0-\dfrac{2}{3}|=\dfrac{2}{3}>\dfrac{1}{2}$. Hence the limit of $s_n=\dfrac{2}{3n}$ is not $\dfrac{2}{3}$

Have I done everything correctly?

Comment: If you're trying to prove that a limit does not exist, this is not enough. You work only suffices to show that the limit is not $\frac{1}{2}$. This definitely has a limit of $0$.

Comment: Couldn't you just say that $\lim s_n = 0$, hence it's not $\frac{2}{3}$ ?

Comment: You'd have to prove it. I don't think this is enough to be a proper proof. You basically assumed that the limit of $s_n$ is $0$ in your work.

Comment: @lmsteffan you could, but you'd need to prove that too. I think the point is that the OP would like a formal proof of his assertion (paying heed to the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition for limits).

Answer (score 1):

Where are you getting $\left | 0 - \frac{2}{3} \right |$? Your sequence has limit zero, but its value is not exactly zero for any $n$. To write the proof with $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, you should find $n$ such that $\left | \frac{2}{3n} - \frac{2}{3} \right | > \frac{1}{2}$. Since $\frac{2}{3n}$ is decreasing, it is natural to achieve this by making $\frac{2}{3n} < \frac{2}{3} - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{6}$. It should not be too hard to find an appropriate $n$ from here.

Another approach is to note that for any $n \geq 2$, your sequence is less than or equal to $\frac{2}{6} = \frac{1}{3}$. This makes it easier to write a proof by choosing $\varepsilon < \frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$|s_n-s|=\left|{2\over 3n}-\frac23\right|={2\over 3}\left|{1\over n}-1\right|={2\over 3}\Bigg(1-\frac1n\Bigg)\ge {2\over 3}\cdot{1\over 2}={1\over 3}=\epsilon_{o}$$